# Wortwahl: für vs. über

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Wie heißt es richtig:

> Gutschein [für|über] einen Kinoabend.

Der Fall "Gutschein über 10€" ist sicherlich richtig, ist aber das Wort "über" auch bei Sachleistungen zulässig?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Duden schreibt [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gutschein):

> Schein, der den Anspruch auf eine bestimmte Sache, auf Waren mit einem
>   bestimmten Gegenwert bestätigt Beispiele
>
> - ein Gutschein auf/für eine Warenprobe
> - Gutscheine ausgeben
> - jemandem [zu Weihnachten] einen Gutschein [im Wert von 100 Euro] schenken
> - einen Gutschein einlösen

Somit wäre `für` auf jeden Fall richtig. Ich finde zwar ad hoc keine Referenz für die folgende Behauptung, jedoch vermute ich, dass wenn die Dienstleistung inkonkret ist, `über` verwendet werden kann. Da der Gutschein im Wert von 10€ inkonkret ist (sprich: man kann den Betrag irgendwo gegen Ware einlösen), wäre `über` in Ordnung.

Comment: Na sowas, ich habe noch nie Gutschein `auf` gehört... man lernt nie aus!

Comment: Danke, sehr gute Referenz.